# php laravel foreach loop giving only 1 result from the array

Tags: php, laravel

what I want to do is to print the data with foreach, but whatever I have done, it prints the last element and not the other one,
where am i going wrong?

I want "PartyIdentification" to return up to each element.

I don't understand if I'm making a mistake in get and sets. Is there a short solution? I want to print more than one property.
the result of my output
[image]

i want to do
[image]

```php
$aa = array(
    0 => ['ID' => ['val' => '4000068418', 'attrs' => ['schemeID="VKN"']]],
    1 => ['ID' => ['val' => '12345678901', 'attrs' => ['schemeID="TICARETSICILNO"']]],
    2 => ['ID' => ['val' => '132546555', 'attrs' => ['schemeID="MERSISNO"']]]
);
$invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party = new \Pvs\eFaturaUBL\Party();
$invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->PartyIdentification = InvoiceBuilder::getasd($aa);
```

```
public static function getasd(array $data)
{
    $asd = new Olusturma();
    $date = array();
    foreach ($data as $datum) {
        $asd->getID($data);
    }
    
    return $asd->getResult();
}
```

```
namespace App\Support\Invoice;

class Olusturma
{
    public $contactDetails = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->contactDetails = new \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyIdentification();
    }

    public function setOlusturma(): Olusturma
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function getID($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $row => $innerArray) {
            foreach ($innerArray as $innerRow => $value) {
                $this->setID($value);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setID($data): Olusturma
    {
        $this->contactDetails->ID = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResult(): \Erkan\eFaturaUBL\PartyIdentification
    {
        return $this->contactDetails;
    }
```

Comment: you keep overriding `$this->contactDetails->ID` so it's going to show the last information you placed there. (`['schemeID="MERSISNO"']`)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, only one class is running, how can i do that

Comment: You are talking about printing? but nothing includes printing or showing the data.

Comment: What I want to do is;
Firstly
array
"$invoice_AccountSupplierParty_Party->PartyIdentification = InvoiceBuilder::getasd($aa);
"I'm sending here,
after that

how many strings are in the interval
that much
I want to return "PartyIdentification ".

Comment: I added what I want to do as an image,
the output given by my codes and what I actually want to do is in the 2nd image

Comment: If you do  `$a = 1;  $a = 2;  $a = 3;`, you're overriding `$a` 's value. `$a` 's value will be equal to `3`, not `[1, 2, 3]`. This is what you're doing with `setID()`